# Show distinct values from IndexedContainers in comboboxes in a table in editing mode

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

**In short:** *The comboboxes in each field of my table in editing mode is giving me a conversion error when selecting an item, but the same logic and containers are working perfectly well outside of the TableFieldFactory (createField()). What am I doing wrong?*

**Longer explanation:**
I have a container with multiple properties (columns) and items (rows). When I edit the table that is connected to this container, I want comboboxes on some of the column fields. I'm using a TableFieldFactory for that, and it is working like a charm.

I want the combobox in each field to contain the *distinct* elements from its respective property. My solution to this was to implement a method in my Container class that iterate through all properties in the container and for each property creates a new IndexedContainer with unique values from that property. The method returns a map with PropertyIds/Containers, so that I, in createField(), can pick each container from each property I want to have comboboxes for.

**Example**

So, say I have three propertyId's, Foo, Bar and Baz which each "contains" several items of which some are the same, like so:

*Foo*

- Chris
- Chris
- Meg
- Meg
- Meg
- Stewie
- Stewie

... and the same for Bar and Baz, only other values...

The getDistinctContainers() method returns a *Map*, looking like this:

```
Key: PropertyId: Foo
Value: Container: contains propertyId [Foo] and the unique values of Foo, ie. [Chris, Meg, Stewie]
Key: PropertyId: Bar
Value: ... and so forth...
```

When I am about to set the container datasource in createField(), the container looks like this (for property Foo):

```
allItemIds: [0, 1, 2]
items: {2={Foo=Stewie}, 1={Foo=Meg}, 0={Foo=Chris}}
propertyIds: [Foo]
```

... which seems alright to me...

Now, the table shows the comboboxes in each field as intended. But when I click an item in a combobox, it gives me the following conversion error:

```
 com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.lang.Integer to model type class java.lang.String. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertToModel(ConverterUtil.java:181)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertToModel(AbstractField.java:745)
```

**Note:**

I tried creating the same scenario outside of the table, and it worked just fine. So it seems that the comboboxes, with the same logic and the same containers, works fine outside the TableFieldFactory and the createFields() method. I can't put my finger on why they shouldn't work in a TableFieldFactory...

**Question:**

- **What do I do to get the comboboxes to set the correct values?**

Here's my Container class:

```
public class SomeContainer extends IndexedContainer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void addContainerProperties() {
        addContainerProperty("Foo", String.class, null);
        addContainerProperty("Bar", String.class, null);
        addContainerProperty("Baz", String.class, null);
    }

    public Map<String, Container> getDistinctContainers() {

        Map<String, Container> m = new HashMap<String, Container>();
        ArrayList<Object> filter = new ArrayList<Object>();

        int id = 0;

        for (Object propertyId : this.getContainerPropertyIds()) {

            Container cont = new IndexedContainer();

            cont.addContainerProperty(propertyId, propertyId.getClass(), null);

            for (Object itemId : this.getItemIds()) {
                Object ob = ((Item) this.getItem(itemId)).getItemProperty(propertyId).getValue();
                if ((!filter.contains(ob.toString())) && (ob != null)) {
                    filter.add(ob.toString());
                    Item item = cont.addItem(id);
                    item.getItemProperty(propertyId).setValue(ob);
                    id++;
                }
            }
            m.put(propertyId.toString(), cont);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

... and here is the relevant code for createField:

```
@Override
public Field<?> createField(Container container, Object itemId, Object propertyId, com.vaadin.ui.Component uiContext) {

    TextField tField = (TextField) DefaultFieldFactory.get().createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);
    tField.setImmediate(true);

    // ...some code here that uses the TextField

    if (propertyId.equals("Foo")) {
        ComboBox select = new ComboBox();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Container> entry : distinctContainers.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(propertyId)) {
                select.setContainerDataSource(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        select.setImmediate(true);
        select.setItemCaptionPropertyId(propertyId);
        select.setItemCaptionMode(AbstractSelect.ITEM_CAPTION_MODE_PROPERTY);

        return select;
    }
    // ...  if statements for Bar and Baz left out for brevity...

    return tField;
}
```

Please help me understand what I'm missing!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the above exception and code snippets we can see that a conversion between `Integer` (presentation type) and `String` (model) is required. In this particular case:

- presentation type: ItemId = {0,1,2}
- model: value of PropertyId = {"Chris", "Meg", "Stewie"}

Since Vaadin has no no built-in IntegerToStringConverter you would need a custom converter:

```
...
select.setContainerDataSource(entry.getValue());
select.setConverter(new Converter<Object, String>() {

    @Override
    public String convertToModel(Object itemId, Class<? extends String> paramClass, Locale paramLocale) throws ConversionException {
        if (itemId != null) {
            IndexedContainer c = (IndexedContainer) entry.getValue();
            Object propertyId = c.getContainerPropertyIds().iterator().next();
            Object name = c.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(propertyId).getValue();
            return (String) name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToPresentation(String value, Class<? extends Object> paramClass, Locale paramLocale) throws ConversionException {
        if (value != null) {
            IndexedContainer c = (IndexedContainer) entry.getValue();
            Object propertyId = c.getContainerPropertyIds().iterator().next();
            for (Object itemId : container.getItemIds()) {
                Object name = c.getContainerProperty(itemId, propertyId).getValue();
                if (value.equals(name)) {
                    return itemId;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getModelType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> getPresentationType() {
        return Object.class;
    }
});
```

Please notice that is not possible to use explicit Integer<-->String conversion

```
select.setConverter(new Converter<Integer, String>());
```

as compiler rejects it. The problem has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834417/eclipse-not-finding-some-declared-methods-in-vaadin-libraries/18834651#18834651).

---

More about Vaadin's converters can be found at:
[Book of Vaadin, Chapter 9.2.3: Converting Between Property Type and Representation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.properties.html#datamodel.properties.converter)
[Changing the default converters for an application](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Changing%20the%20default%20converters%20for%20an%20application)
[Creating your own converter for String - MyType conversion](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+your+own+converter+for+String+-+MyType+conversion)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I reverted back to a more "dirty" solution by using lists instead of containers as input to my comboboxes. I will check this out as soon as I have time!