# Eclipse not finding some declared methods (in Vaadin libraries)

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I'm having a big problem and I don't know if the problem is in my IDE's fault, Vaadin or I'm doing something really wrong. Eclipse is not finding some methods when I try to use them (but they are there when listing the methods for an object after adding a dot)

I can give you an example, but there are more (I can give more if it's needed):

I want to set a Converter to a ComboBox. There are two methods for it:

```
public void setConverter(java.lang.Class<?> datamodelType)

public void setConverter(Converter<T,?> converter)
```

I want to use the second one, so I do this:

```
myCombobox.setConverter(new Converter<User, Integer>(){

   // Some interface methods

});
```

But then Eclipse sets the method name in red and when I hover I get this:

```
The method setConverter(Class<?>) in the type AbstractField<Object> is not applicable for the arguments (new Converter<User,Integer>(){})
```

It's like it doesn't know that the other method exists.
When I go check the class, the method of course exists, as Eclipse listed first.

I really don't know why is this happening, I appreciate any clue or thought.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using the right `Converter` interface? ie. `com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBox` extends `AbstractField<Object>` so `T` for `ComboBox` is `Object`.

Since generic type parameters can not be substituted by subclasses (unless specified) you'll have to give that method a `Converter<Object, ?>` or it's not matching the method signature.

```
myCombobox.setConverter(new Converter<Object, Integer>() {
    // ... cast to `User` if you like
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it, but I still can't understand the other big problem I have this this:
calendar.setHandler(new EventClickHandler(){

 @Override
        public void eventClick(EventClick event)
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          
         }
});

This is telling me to use another method, and no generics involved this time... I guess I'll have to open a new thread for it. Thanks!